# How can I change the text in Tweets on Twitter?

Tags: javascript, twitter, replace, greasemonkey

There's this one twitter account that I'm following that posts tweets in military time in a different time zone. I'm trying to use javascript with the GreaseMonkey Addon in Firefox to change the text to the appropriate timezone and in regular time. The problem is that I can't seem to get it to work.

The account I'm following:
https://twitter.com/pso2_emg_bot

The Script I used:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        PSO2 Emg Bot Script
// @namespace   Twitter
// @description Convert time to EST
// @include     https://twitter.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

function replaceText(){
var theDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text");
var theText = theDiv .innerHTML;

// Replace words
theText = theText.replace("4:00~4:30", "2:00 P.M. ~ 2:30 P.M.");
theText = theText.replace("14:00~14:30", "12:00 A.M. ~ 12:30 A.M.");
theText = theText.replace("15:00~15:30", "1:00 A.M. ~ 1:30 A.M.");
theText = theText.replace("16:00~16:30", "2:00 A.M. ~ 2:30 A.M.");

theDiv.innerHTML = theText;
}
```

It's incomplete at the moment since I just need to get it to work before I include all times for the script to search for. If anyone can tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: "Military time"? You mean normal time?

Answer (score 2):

- You have defined a function, `function replaceText()`, but there is
  nothing in your script that calls that function, so nothing is
  executed.
- Note that `theDiv` will actually contain an array of divs, so you can't get set or set it's innerHTML this way.
- In the twitter page you mention, the time is separated by a character that it's not ~, but something outside screen fonts ability to display. Use copy+paste to get that correctly.
- There is also a syntax error in line 11, you left a space inside `theDiv .innerHTML;`

Twitter has jQuery loaded, so it would be probably easier to use that instead of vanilla JS in your case.

```
//...
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = unsafeWindow.$;
var theDivs = $(".js-tweet-text");

theDivs.each(function(){
    var theText = $(this).text();

    theText = theText.replace("7:00～7:30", "7:00 P.M. ~ 7:30 P.M.");
    //other replacements you want to make.
    //consider using a regular expression instead of one line for each hour.
    $(this).text(theText);
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this point:                                  _In the twitter page you mention, the time is separated by a character that it's not ~, but something outside screen fonts ability to display. Use copy+paste to get that correctly._      Because I copy and pasted the time in the original script, which makes me believe that the browser automatically converted the character. Also, the script you provided doesn't seem to function in greasemonkey.

Comment: Actually nevermind. I just had to reinstall the script. hank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

1. Tweets are added via AJAX, so you need to use AJAX-aware scripting.  Below, I will show how to do this with [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891).
2. Don't use `innerHTML`.  It will bust things (plus it's slower).  Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or "DOM techniques" (also shown below).
3. Use regex to get the time, so that a bazillion different `.replace()` statements aren't needed.

Putting that all together, here is **a complete working script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _PSO2 Emg Bot Script
// @namespace   Twitter
// @description Convert time to EST
// @include     https://twitter.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("p.js-tweet-text", ChangeSpecialTimeStrs);

function ChangeSpecialTimeStrs (jNode) {
    var node    = jNode[0];

    //-- Search only in the first-level text nodes of this paragraph.
    for (var K = 0, numC = node.childNodes.length;  K < numC;  ++K) {
        var childNode = node.childNodes[K];
        if (childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            if (childNode.nodeValue.length > 8)  {
                //-- Anything shorter can't have our kind of string.
                childNode.nodeValue  = childNode.nodeValue.replace (
                    /*-- This matches strings like: "5:00~15:30"
                        Where "~" may be unicode FF5E
                    */
                    /\b(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(?:~|\uFF5E)(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\b/gi,
                    shiftHourStr
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function shiftHourStr (
    matchedStr,                 //- Housekeeping supplied by .replace()
    hour1Str, minute1Str,       //- Payload vals from () groups
    hour2Str, minute2Str,       //- Payload vals from () groups
    matchOffset, totalString    //- Housekeeping supplied by .replace()
) {
    //-- Return a string with a format like: "12:00 A.M. ~ 12:30 A.M."
    const tzOffsetHours = 10;
    var newHr1Arry      = getHourOffset (hour1Str, tzOffsetHours);
    var newHr2Arry      = getHourOffset (hour2Str, tzOffsetHours);
    var outputStr       = newHr1Arry[0]     //-- Hour value
                        + ":" + minute1Str
                        + newHr1Arry[1]     //-- AM or PM
                        + " ~ "
                        + newHr2Arry[0]     //-- Hour value
                        + ":" + minute2Str
                        + newHr2Arry[1]     //-- AM or PM
                        ;
    return outputStr;
};

function getHourOffset (hourVal, hoursOffset) {
    var amPmStr     = "A.M.";
    var newHourVal  = parseInt (hourVal, 10) + hoursOffset;

    if (newHourVal > 23) {
        newHourVal -= 24;
    }
    if (newHourVal >= 12) {
        newHourVal -= 12;
        amPmStr     = "P.M.";
    }
    if (newHourVal == 0) {
        newHourVal  = 12;
        amPmStr     = "A.M.";
    }
    return [newHourVal, " " + amPmStr];
}
```